# Spark throws Not Serializable Exception inside a foreachRDD operation

Tags: scala, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

i'm trying to implement an observer pattern using scala and spark streaming. the idea is that whenever i receive a record from the stream (from kafka) i notify the observer by calling the method "notifyObservers" inside the closure. here's the code:

the stream is provided by the kafka utils.
the method notifyObserver is defined into an abstract class following the rules of the pattern.
the error I think is related on the fact that methods cant be serialize.
Am I thinking correctly? and if it was, what kind of solution should I follow?
thanks

```
def onMessageConsumed() = {
    stream.foreachRDD(rdd => {
      rdd.foreach(consumerRecord => {
        val record = new Record[T](consumerRecord.topic(), 
                                   consumerRecord.value())
        //notify observers with the record to compute
        notifyObservers(record)
      })
    })
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the classes that are used in the code that is sent to other executors (executed in `foreach`, etc.), should implement `Serializable` interface.

also, if you're notification code requires connection to some resource, you need to wrap `foreach` into `foreachPartition`, something like this:

```scala
stream.foreachRDD(rdd => {
   rdd.foreachPartition(rddPartition =>
      // setup connection to external component      
      rddPartition.foreach(consumerRecord => {
        val record = new Record[T](consumerRecord.topic(), 
                                   consumerRecord.value())
        notifyObservers(record)
      })
      // close connection to external component
   })
  })
```